# symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: __glewDeleteFramebuffersEXT

Tags: c++, opengl, shared-libraries

I am compiling an application on linux which is based on QT4, OpenGL, GLEW, ...

The compilation processes completes with no error. but I get this runtime error:

```
 symbol lookup error: libtgt.so.1: undefined symbol: __glewDeleteFramebuffersEXT
```

I have no idea if it has anything to do with OpenGL version?

I have this application compiled and run on another machine (so pretty sure that nothing is wrong with the libraries).

I need to mention libglew and libglew-dev versions are exactly the same on the problematic and working machines.

Comment: Are you using any other OpenGL related libraries that you have not listed in your question?  Ensure you are linking your libraries in the correct order.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Actually the provided make files take care of the linkage. I ran the same make file on my laptop with Ubuntu 12.04 and openGL 3 and it worked properly. But on my desktop again with Ubuntu 12.04 but OpenGL 2 it shows this run time error. However to me it does not seem `OpenGL` problem. it looks more like glew problem.

Comment: You're probably trying to link to the dynamic GLEW library when only the static is available or visa versa. Since using the dynamic (shared) GLEW library is not particularly useful, I would suggest defining `GLEW_STATIC` and using the static library.

Comment: Basically the application has its own glew.h in a folder, so based on your comment when I added -lGLEW and -lGLU and -lGL to the makefile the runtime error disappeared however, now I'm getting `Failed to compile vertex shader` I do not know if it has anything to do with glew?

Comment: The vertex shader not compiling probably is not because of GLEW. Do you get a specific error message about the vertex shader?

Comment: I do not have the error right now on my machine, I'll post it asap. I guess I finally have to update OpenGL to version 3 (maybe OpenGL and GLEW version do not match)